# How to add multiple rows into one row with total

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add multiple rows into one row with total?  I am trying to add two rows of data and output the data into one row for one particular job. I have cut output down to one job but I will be putting multiple jobs in the output once I figure out how to get two rows to combine to one.  Each job has two employees so I will have to add both employees hours together for a total hours worked per job.

```
SELECT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJ.strJobDescription
    ,TJS.strJobStatus
    ,SUM(TJE.intHoursWorked) AS intTotalHoursWorked

FROM
     TJobs          AS TJ
    ,TJobStatus     AS TJS
    ,TJobEmployees  AS TJE
    ,TEmployees     AS TE
WHERE
    TJ.intJobID         =       TJE.intJobID
AND TJ.intJobStatusID   =       TJS.intJobStatusID
AND TE.intEmployeeID    =       TJE.intEmployeeID
AND TJ.intJobID = 1
GROUP BY
    TJ.intJobID
   ,TJE.intEmployeeID
   ,TJ.strJobDescription
   ,TJS.strJobStatus
   ,TJE.intHoursWorked


 /*

     Output I'm Getting

    intJobID    strJobStatus    intTotalHoursWorked
       1          Complete              50
       1          Complete              42

     Wanted Output

    intJobID    strJobStatus    intTotalHoursWorked
       1          Complete              92

 */
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJS.strJobStatus
    ,SUM(TJE.intHoursWorked) AS intTotalHoursWorked

...
...
GROUP BY
    TJ.intJobID
   ,TJS.strJobStatus
```

I double check your query and you have too many tables. Because you dont really need `TEmployees`

```
SELECT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJ.strJobDescription
    ,TJS.strJobStatus
    ,SUM(TJE.intHoursWorked) AS intTotalHoursWorked

FROM TJobs          AS TJ
JOIN TJobStatus     AS TJS
  ON TJ.intJobStatusID =  TJS.intJobStatusID
JOIN TJobEmployees  AS TJE
  ON TJ.intJobID       =  TJE.intJobID
GROUP BY
    TJ.intJobID
   ,TJS.strJobStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using CTE..since we don't know your data and what column in group by caused mutiple columns

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT
     TJ.intJobID
    ,TJ.strJobDescription
    ,TJS.strJobStatus
    ,SUM(TJE.intHoursWorked) AS intTotalHoursWorked

FROM
     TJobs          AS TJ
    ,TJobStatus     AS TJS
    ,TJobEmployees  AS TJE
    ,TEmployees     AS TE
WHERE
    TJ.intJobID         =       TJE.intJobID
AND TJ.intJobStatusID   =       TJS.intJobStatusID
AND TE.intEmployeeID    =       TJE.intEmployeeID
AND TJ.intJobID = 1
GROUP BY
    TJ.intJobID
   ,TJE.intEmployeeID
   ,TJ.strJobDescription
   ,TJS.strJobStatus
   ,TJE.intHoursWorked
)
select 
intJobID,
max(strJobStatus) as 'strJobStatus',
sum(intTotalHoursWorked) as 'intTotalHoursWorked'
from cte
```